# Filtering Mapbox Studio dataset with mapbox-gl.js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to extend a map built in Mapbox Studio with advanced filtering options (e.g., display only selected data types) with Mapbox GL JS for a web-based application. The available examples use imported GeoJSON data but my data is provided by Mapbox Studio's dataset editor. My JavaScript skills are limited so I'm having trouble updating the filter code to work with my dataset. Any recommendations or relevant samples of this type of interaction?

I've mocked up a basic interaction for testing filters using buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/jsonfrank/sn5j0pr8/

```
document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var filter = ['==', 'Type', event.target.id.substr('button-'.length)];
  map.setFilter('map-data-test-040816', filter);
});
```

I'd like to be able to do more advanced filtering based on multiple datatypes, possibly like this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? Where are you getting stuck? The style in the JSfiddle doesn't seem to use a dataset. You're on the right track - nothing is drastically different just because you're using a dataset instead of a local GeoJSON file.